# Combining group_by and e.divisive in R : How to find slope changes for different ids

Tags: r, group-by

I have been trying to identify the slope changes for my timeseries variable x for different ids. I have managed to do it for a single id as follows:

```
library(ecp)
library(dplyr)
x<- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27)
timev <-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25)

df <- data.frame(x, timev)
plot(df)

div_y <- e.divisive(X = df, sig.lvl=.01, min.size=3)
```

Which properly spots the slope change (div_y$estimates are [1]  1 14 26 ).

However, I have not been able to do the same if I introduce different ids.

If I do :

```
library(ecp)
library(dplyr)
id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)

x<- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27)
timev <-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25)

df <- data.frame(id, x, timev)


div_y <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% e.divisive(X = df, sig.lvl=.01, min.size=3)
```

I get the following error:

> Error in 1:R : NA/NaN argument In addition: Warning messages: 1: In if
> (R == 0) return(0) :   the condition has length > 1 and only the first
> element will be used 2: In 1:R : numerical expression has 3 elements:
> only the first used

It looks like `group_by()` doesn't work with `e.divisive()`, any ideas of any equivalent functions or any ways to "rephrase"? Many thanks

Comment: Which package is `e.divisive()` from?

Comment: ecp, I updated my question to clarify :)